# Javascript Split String Without Separator

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Basically, I have a string of unknown numbers (determined by user input + my own math), and I need to split this string into 3 parts.

For example, I may have "1273498". I need to split it at the two characters, and the 3rd and 4th from the RIGHT, like so:
127
34
98

Another example: 1234567890 would need to be:
123456
78
90

Currently, I am accomplishing it this way:

```
// get first input box value
var depositgold = document.getElementById('v-gold').value;
// set it to 0 if it's empty
if(depositgold == null || depositgold == '')
    depositgold = 0;

// second input box value
var depositsilver = document.getElementById('v-silver').value;
if(depositsilver == null || depositsilver == '')
    depositsilver = 0;

// third input box value
var depositcopper = document.getElementById('v-copper').value;
if(depositcopper == null || depositcopper == '')
    depositcopper = 0;

// combine the 3 input box values (adding dec to make split easier)
var depositnums = depositgold + '.' + depositsilver + depositcopper;

// do some math on our new value, then split it at out dec
var deposit12 = (0.15 * depositnums).toFixed(4).split(".");
// split the last part of the above split into 4 characters
var result12 = deposit12[1].split("", 3);
// keep the first part of out dec split
var deposit12gold = deposit12[0];
// combine the second part split results into paired numbers
var deposit12silver = result12[0] + result12[1];
var deposit12copper = result12[2] + result12[3];

// repeat the above process
var deposit24 = (0.30 * depositnums).toFixed(4).split(".");
var result24 = deposit24[1].split("", 3);
var deposit24gold = deposit24[0];
var deposit24silver = result24[0] + result24[1];
var deposit24copper = result24[2] + result24[3];

var deposit48 = (0.60 * depositnums).toFixed(4).split(".");
var result48 = deposit48[1].split("", 3);
var deposit48gold = deposit48[0];
var deposit48silver = result48[0] + result48[1];
var deposit48copper = result48[2] + result48[3];
```

I know there must be a much better (and more sane) way of accomplishing the above - I need to do it several more times for this project, and I'm certainly not looking forward to continuing to do it this way.

I am new to JS and programming, so laugh away, just try not to laugh too hard ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I need to split it at the **LAST** two characters, and the two characters before the last two.

Answer (score 5):

Try something along these lines:

```
var str = "123412341";
var matches = str.match(/(.+?)?(.{2})?(.{2})?$/);

// matches[1] = 12341
// matches[2] = 23
// matches[3] = 41
```

You may want to modify the RegEx depending on your input, currently all groups are optional.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the substring method

```
var number = 123456789;
var one = number.substring( 0, number.length - 4 );
var two = number.substring( number.length -4, number.length - 2);
var three = number.substring( number.length - 2 );
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `substr()` method for this:

```
var L = mystring.length
var part1 = mystring.substr(0,L-4);
var part2 = mystring.substr(L-4,2);
var part3 = mystring.substr(L-2,2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
('1234'+'56'+'78').match(/(\d*)(\d\d)(\d\d)/)
["12345678", "1234", "56", "78"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 1234567890;

number = number.toString();

var a = number.substr(0, number.length - 4),
    b = number.substr(-2),
    c = number.substr(number.length - 4, 2);

console.log(a, b, c);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/V99K3/).

#### Output

> 123456 90 78

Answer (score 1):

here is a function i made:

```
/**
 * @param num A number to split like 382203849238
 * @return Returns an array of size 3, where index 0 = 38220384, index 1 = 92, index 2 = 38 based on the example above
*/
function splitNumbers(num) {
    var num = (typeof num == 'string' || typeof num == 'String') ? parseInt(num) : num,
        rem = num % 10000;
    return [Math.floor(num / 10000), Math.floor(rem / 100), rem % 100];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Function to parse code in 3 parts
function parse_code_Split (code)
{
    var len = code.length;
    var divisor = (len / 3) >> 0; // get whole number
    console.log(divisor);
    var stringReg = "";
    var regexp = ".{1,"  + divisor + "}";
    try{
        stringReg = new RegExp(regexp,"g");
    }catch(Error){
        window.console.log(Error.message);
    }

    codeSplit = code.match(stringReg);

    // window.console.log(" codeSplit[0] " + codeSplit[0]);
    // window.console.log(" codeSplit[1] " + codeSplit[1]);
    // window.console.log(" codeSplit[2] " + codeSplit[2]);
    // window.console.log(" codeSplit[3] " + codeSplit[3]); // remainder

    return codeSplit;
}
```